# Can my Perl program execute code stored in a database?

Tags: mysql, perl, eval

Is it possible to save some Perl code in a database, retrieve it using a `select` statement, and execute that Perl code?

I have tried using [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval), but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I'm trying right now and it doesn't seem to work:

```
my $temp = $qryResults[0];
print $temp . "\n";
eval{"$temp"};
```

The output is `$con->Disconnect();exit;`

Comment: @TheGNUGuy Please explain why you want to do this. Your example itself shows one security problem. There are many many many others. If you explain the *why* and the *what*, maybe we can offer a safer alternative.

Comment: Please don't do this. Tell us why you think you have to do this and perhaps we can lead you down a better path. :)

Comment: I am trying to make a jabber bot that I can use to control one of my remote machines.  I want to use the database to store commands and actions the bot can perform.

Comment: As long as the source of the eval'ed content is trusted (untainted) there is nothing wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: @mrjoltcola: That (trusted source) is a big *if*, and hard to ensure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need:

```
eval $temp;
```

The reason your version didn't work was due to the block form of eval evaluating it as if you had written a simple string:

```
eval{"perl code here"}
```

It is like writing this line of Perl:

```
"Perl code here"
```

It isn't code; it's a string.

The block form evaluates what is inside the block. If a string is inside the block, it's just a string, not a script.

The string form evaluates what is inside the string.

Comment: Yes.  Even though they're both called `eval`, `eval { BLOCK }` and `eval "STRING"` are **not** interchangeable.

Comment: Many tearful programming sessions began with "hey, if I just use eval...".  My advice: DON'T.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; if I remove the curly brackets then it works.

Comment: Good luck, you're going to need it.